# Find interval of $c$ such that $2e^{2x} -(c+1)e^x +2 \ge 0$ for all $x\in R$

Tags: quadratics

Now I know the normal method of manipulation which will get us
$$c+1\le 2(e^x + \frac{1}{e^x})$$
ie. $c\le 3$

But can I do it by assume $e^x=t$ and then resolving the quadratic? What complications would $t>0$ bring into it? I realise that setting $D<0$ will get the same answer but that doesn’t always work so I want to know how to adjust for $t>0$ or any other condition on the variable in a general function

Comment: Yes you can see it as a quadratic of $t$.

Comment: What is $p$ in the title and how did it disappear in your work?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy it’s not nothing, just an accident. Fixed it now

Answer (score 1):

I am straring with $$c+1\le 2(e^x + \frac{1}{e^x})$$ which you wrote in your attempt, but there is an extra $p$ factor in the title.

Hints: The inequality we need is $t^{2}+1-(c+ 1) t/2 \geq 0$ for all $t >0$. The left side is minimized when $t=\frac {c+1}  4$. You have to consider the cases $ c+1>0$ and $ c+1\leq 0$ separately.In the second case the inequality is automatically satisfied so there is no extra condition on $c$. In the first case the condition is $t^{2}+1-(c+ 1) t/2 \geq 0$ for $t=\frac {c+1} 4$.  Can you now show that the answer is $(-\infty, 3]$?